# How to insert multiple rows using node.js, db-migrate, postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, insert, migration, dbmigrate

I have a roles migrations.

```
'use strict';

var dbm;
var type;
var seed;

/**
  * We receive the dbmigrate dependency from dbmigrate initially.
  * This enables us to not have to rely on NODE_PATH.
  */
exports.setup = function (options, seedLink) {
  dbm = options.dbmigrate;
  type = dbm.dataType;
  seed = seedLink;
};

exports.up = function (db) {
  return db.createTable('roles', {
    role_id: { type: 'int', primaryKey: true, unique: true, autoIncrement: true },
    role_name: 'text',
  })
}

exports.down = function (db) {
  return db.dropTable('roles')
};

exports._meta = {
  "version": 1
};
```

Now, I would like to set some default roles. How am I suppose to do that?

```
'use strict';

var dbm;
var type;
var seed;

/**
  * We receive the dbmigrate dependency from dbmigrate initially.
  * This enables us to not have to rely on NODE_PATH.
  */

exports.setup = function (options, seedLink) {
  dbm = options.dbmigrate;
  type = dbm.dataType;
  seed = seedLink;
};

exports.up = function (db) {
  const sql = "DELETE FROM roles"
  db.runSql(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
  })

  return db.insert(
    'roles',
    ['user_role'],
    [['admin', 'technician']]
  )
};

exports.down = function (db) {
  const sql = "DELETE FROM roles"
  db.runSql(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
  })
  return null
};

exports._meta = {
  "version": 1
};
```

No matter what I try I always get

> unterminated quoted string at or near "'admin);"

as an error.

It runs in the docker container and I already ran `run migrate_up` for both migrations

The documentation states I need to do this: `insert(tableName, columnNameArray, valueArray, callback)`

So, how do I add multiple rows in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I managed to insert them one by one, push their promises into array and then call promise all on them. so in your case.

```
exports.up = function (db) {
  const sql = "DELETE FROM roles"
  db.runSql(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
  })
  

  const promises = [];

  promises.push(db.insert('roles', { user_role : 'admin'}))
  promises.push(db.insert('roles', { user_role : 'technician'}))

  return Promise.all(promises)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. Hope it helps someone else

```
'use strict'

var dbm
var type
var seed

/**
 * We receive the dbmigrate dependency from dbmigrate initially.
 * This enables us to not have to rely on NODE_PATH.
 */
exports.setup = function (options, seedLink) {
  dbm = options.dbmigrate
  type = dbm.dataType
  seed = seedLink
}

exports.up = function (db) {
  // If there are roles, we need to delete them anyway
  const sql = 'DELETE FROM roles'
  db.runSql(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
  })

  return db.insert('roles', ['role_name'], ['admin']).then(
    function (result) {
      return db.insert('roles', ['role_name'], ['technician'])
    },
    function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
    },
  )
}

exports.down = function (db) {
  const sql = 'DELETE FROM roles'
  db.runSql(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
  })
  return null
}

exports._meta = {
  version: 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.(Made a small modification to @Rassix's answer)

```
exports.up = function (db) {
  const promises = [];
  promises.push(db.insert('roles', ['user_role'] , ['Admin']));
  promises.push(db.insert('roles', ['user_role'] ,['Technician']));
  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```